# How to add a Condition to laravel voyager relationship BelongsToMany

Tags: javascript, laravel, eloquent, voyager

I need to get variants where `parent_id` is `null` in Belongs To Many Relation in `Laravel Voyager`

`relation.blade.php`

```html
<select
    class="form-control @if(isset($options->taggable) && $options->taggable == 'on') select2-taggable @else select2-ajax @endif"
    name="{{ $relationshipField }}[]" multiple
    data-get-items-route="{{route('voyager.' . $dataType->slug.'.relation')}}" data-get-items-field="{{$row->field}}"
    @if(isset($options->taggable) && $options->taggable == 'on')
    data-route="{{ route('voyager.'.\Illuminate\Support\Str::slug($options->table).'.store') }}"
    data-label="{{$options->label}}"
    data-error-message="{{__('voyager::bread.error_tagging')}}"
    @endif
    >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to customise the controller called by the route : `{{route('voyager.' . $dataType->slug.'.relation')}}` which will be  `$breadController.'@relation'`. You can in the said controller override the public method `relation` by inspiring you on [the original one](https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/blob/1.3/src/Http/Controllers/VoyagerBaseController.php) (l.822)  to send back the eloquent models it normally would filtered by a `->where('parent_id', null)` (in both l.838 and l.840).

You might also be interested in looking into the [Query Scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#query-scopes) offered by Laravel.